# How do I check whether a value is 1 or 0 in SQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

So I've setup my database connection and it does connect.
Now I want to check each row in my table whether the column `isactivated` is either `0` or `1` because it's a **bit** but I don't know how to do it.

Would I execute a query? Would I store all the rows in a list and then check?

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed..");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your rows, then do *what* with them?

Comment: @TheGeneral `I want to check each row in my table wether the column isactivated is either 0 or 1 because it's a bit`

Comment: Which didn't answer my question, Do you want to count them, do you want to filter my this field, do you want to just check any exists

Comment: It is by far the most beginners question which can be answered with any of beginners tutorial. Nobody was born with all the knowledge you need to learn.

Answer (score 3):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT column FROM table", connection);
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    // 0 = false, 1 = true,
    bool result = (bool)reader[0];

    //... do whatever you wanna do with the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Taken from [msdn-lib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In the SqlDataReader should be all your data including your isactivated column, which you then can check for its respective values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the field you can implement something like this:

```
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString)) {
    try {
      connection.Open();

      // connection.Open() either succeeds (and so we print the message) 
      // or throw an exception; no need to check 
      Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

      //TODO: edit the SQL if required
      string sql =
        @"select IsActivated
            from MyTable";

      using (var query = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) {
        using (var reader = query.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (reader.Read()) {
            // Now it's time to answer your question: let's read the value 
            //   reader["IsActivated"] - value of IsActivated as an Object
            //   Convert.ToBoolean     - let .Net do all low level work for you
            bool isActivated = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsActivated"]);

            // Uncomment, if you insist on 0, 1
            // int bit = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IsActivated"]);

            //TODO: field has been read into isActivated; put relevant code here  
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (DataException e) { // Be specific: we know how to process data errors only
      Console.WriteLine(e);

      throw;
    }
  }
```